# What does a Turing machine do when it reaches the end of it's input?

Tags: turing-machines

If a Turing Machine has an input tape of 01011, for example, what happens if you reach the end of that sequence without reaching any resolution within the Turing Machine?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: also possibly related: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3119/is-it-decidable-whether-a-tm-reaches-some-position-on-the-tape

Answer (score 3):

The tape is infinite, the input does not only consist of 5 cells. To the left and right, the tape is blank (i.e. filled with 0, or possibly some other symbol if you have more than  two). There is no "end of the sequence", the turing machine will continue running its program until it halts (which might be never).